# Bluebird promise resolve or reject not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This is a function which creates a directory only if that directory doesn't  exist already. Here I'm using `fs.mkdirSync` function to create directory. Usually this function returns value `undefined` if directory creation is successful or error message if failed to create.
I have handled promise resolve and reject methods using a `if` condition.  In my `home` directory, there are no directories called `Projects` and `test`. When i run the function with `dirName`, `/home/srinesh/Projects/test/hello`, In this case `createDir` generate a error. But the issue I'm struggling with is, the error message doesn't contain `createDir error` string which tells it didn't have gone through `promise`'s `reject` function. Finally, what i want to know is how to handle `Sync`function's errors with `promises`.

Error message:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/home/dazz/Projects/test/hello'
```

The Code:

```
var filePath = '/home/srinesh/Projects/test/hello';
var createDir = function (dirName) {
  return new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var result = fs.mkdirSync(dirName);
    if(result == undefined){resolve('folder created successfully!');}
    else {reject('createDir error: '+result);}
  })
};

var createProject = function (filePath) {
        var result = createDir(filePath);
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
};
```

Comment: Your `createProject` thing is a syntax error - there's a stray `})` in the middle, and you're calling `.catch()` on nothing. How does it actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.mkdirSync` always returns `undefined`, in case of an error it will just throw. You can wrap your `fs.mkdirSync` in a `try-catch` and `reject` whenever your code throws, but a more elegant solution would be to use the async version of the function `fs.mkdir` as following.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var filePath =  __dirname + '/dummyFolder';
var createDir = function (dirName) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var result = fs.mkdir(dirName, (err, folder) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve("folder created successfully");
        }
    });
  })
};

var createProject = function (filePath) {
    createDir(filePath)
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log(val);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
};


createProject(filePath);
```